# I can't find liferay security & permission's blogs.xml

Tags: security, permissions, liferay, portlet

I can't find liferay security & permission's blogs.xml anywhere on my liferay folder. Can anyone please tell me what to do and assist on this. Thank you.

My purpose is to edit user's permission in the user configuration through code instead of setting in the main panel.

Source : https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/resource-actions/blogs.xml

http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en

Comment: did you check the current branch (or download the source for the version that you're actually running)? You're linking to master, which is what is available for the upcoming version. Please check the code matching whatever you currently run (the devguide you link suggests it's 6.2). Also, you might want to leave the files as they are and just use the API to programmatically update the permissions.

Comment: Hi, I just downloaded the source code since I couldn't find the branch anywhere. Yes I'm using 6.2 and have downloaded 6.2 source code. As for permissions, I want to do via code without going through API. Now, how do I merge the files from github source code to my existing liferay. All help is much appreciated, thanks.